# Export OpenAPI to native/plain javascript

Tags: javascript, openapi

Friends convinced me to use OpenAPI to document the REST API for my embedded web server project.
Now I struck at the point to generate/export javascript code that I can integrate into my embedded server to deliver it to clients.
Until now I could not find a tool that can generate native javascript modules, that I can easily embed into my webserver.

I used the openapi-generator to generate javascript code. Unfortunately all generators that I found require node.js or other additional platforms: [openapi generators](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/).

With searching the internet I could not find suitable tools that can generate plain/native javascript. I started to read openapi-generator manual about creating custom extensions. But I recognized that my friend's request to provide a well defined API specification gets more and more complex and I think about switching back to a non-specified API with custom/propriatory/handwritten javascript code.

Does anyone know if there are OpenAPI code generators that can generate native javascript (without any additional libraries)?

Thank you

Comment: fyi this is off-topic, as there's no programming question here - just a basic set of requirements, and a request for tool/product/framework recommendations. Open-ended/broad questions are off-topic, as are opinion-based questions and recommendation-based questions.  Please read [ask], as well as how to write a [mcve] with all relevant details (your code, sample input, expected vs actual behavior, errors, etc).